# Android Resource Name From Xamarin Forms Button

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, google-play

The Play Store now allows you to specify credentials for the Pre-launch Report emulator to use. In order for the emulators to know which text field to add the credentials to and which button to click to login, it asks for the text field and button's Resource Name.

Do any of the Xamarin Form's properties translate into a Resource name? I tried looking in the **/obj/** and **/bin/** folders after building my app to see if one of the files had anything like this but I did not find anything.

Possible properties that I can think of that might map to a Resource Name:

```
StyleId
AutomationId
ClassId
AutomationProperties.Name (in XF 2.3.5)
```

If nothing maps over, would you know of a way to use a custom renderer to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to use the Pre-launch reports with `Xamarin.Forms`:

**1)** Define a Login `Activity` via a Layout XML resource that includes a username & password `Entry` fields, a login button is optional and if not supplied, the robots will tap every available button on the screen.

You can either define this `Activity` as your main launcher (or the activity that gets launched after "splash screen" activity) and perform the login authentication independently of Xamarin.Forms code, of course you can access PCL/NStd library code. After authentication success, proceed to the "MainActivity" which does the normal Xamarin.Forms initiation or present this Login Activity (or ViewGroup, Fragment, ...) via a custom renderer (or a dependency service which is the easiest for a complete Activity....)

Now you know the resource ids that Google needs as they are hardcoded in the Login layout XML...

**2)** Publish your app as an **Alpha/Beta** and either have it auto-login to a test account or just present a login screen that have a pre-supplied test account user and pwd filled in and have those entries set to read-only. The robot will tap the login button.

Option 2 is the quickest and easiest to setup as you would already have a login Page and just need to define a test account id/pwd to those two fields as defaults and then set those fields to read-only....

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was hoping I would not have to recreate my login screen, but I guess it would be pretty wasteful to create a custom renderer just to add the damn Resource Name to the `Button` and 2 `Entry`s

Comment: @hvaughan3 Use Option 2, you could do it by just changing a few lines of code (use conditionals: #if) and publish your test app as a private alpha/beta.

Comment: Part of the purpose of the pre-launch reports is to regression test each release so that you can detect problems as devices, SDKs, and your code, change over time. Creating a custom build for every version of the app would be less than ideal.

Comment: @EdwardBrey You do not have to create different builds, but to use the account login feature within the robot testing, you would need to have some type of test acct and when the robot logs into it to, your backend service provides either a custom dataset, or a separate endpoint to connect to.

Comment: Without a custom build or resource names for the robot to enter credentials, how does the app or backend know whether the user is a robot or a human and when to use a test account?

Comment: @EdwardBrey Via the fact that it is using test credentials (i.e. same way that you would "flag" test accts for your developers/QA/testers in order to not effect production data)

Comment: @SushiHangover It sounds like you're talking about Option 1, where you have an native Activity with named resources that the robot can use. I was commenting on Option 2, where the code is modified with `#if` statements to achieve the test login. Building a modified version of the code for every release can be done, but it adds complexity to the deployment pipeline.